# How to create two coloured single div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create the div with two colors (refer below img),But i'm able to do only 50% each half. How to create the below with two different colors? Please help me out [image]

Comment: To do it with one div you are going to need to use pseudo elements such as :before or :after. Can i ask why this needs to be only one div?

Comment: @LewisBrowne I should place the text above the div. The text is of continuous flow.So I'm thinking that one div would solve my problem.

Comment: @LewisBrowne Any other way around to achieve like using multiple div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```css
#x {
 width: 200px;
 height: 0px;
 border-top: 100px solid red;
 border-left: 100px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="x">
</div>
```

As we have used borders to create the div, you may have to position inner contents of the division accordingly.
For e.g.

```css
#x {
 width: 200px;
 height: 0px;
 border-top: 100px solid red;
 border-left: 100px solid green;
}

#y {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="x">
  <div id="y">
    Hi there! I am the inner content! :)
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: great .Thanks :)

Comment: It works, although it should be mentioned that any content "inside" the div will appear underneath the fat borders (at the intersection point of both)

Comment: How can i make the text appear above the div?

Comment: Thanks @PeterB, I forgot to mention that, I have edited the answer... Please check it out :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a background gradient for this adjusting the angle and stops as needed:

```css
div {
height: 100px;
background: linear-gradient(60deg, green 0%, green 16%, red 16%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe more of a gimmick but if you know the height of the div, you can play around with a linear-gradient to match what you want.

```css
div {
  height: 225px;
  width: 100%;

  background: #00ff00;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(40deg, #00ff00 0%, #30ff30 25%, #0000ff 25%, #0000e8 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #00ff00 0%,#30ff30 25%,#0000ff 25%,#0000e8 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #00ff00 0%,#30ff30 25%,#0000ff 25%,#0000e8 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ff00', endColorstr='#0000e8',GradientType=1 );
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use :before and :after elements to achieve this with just one div but if you were able to use more than one then you could do this:

Create an outer rectangle which contains the red and green colours and put an overflow hidden on this one so that it keeps the overall thing looking like a rectangle. Then inside you could create a red rectangle and a green rectangle but put a transform: skew on the red rectangle so that it created the diagonal line. Use z-index to position the red rectangle over the top of the green rectangle and it should help you achieve this.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle, so i can understand well .TIA